# Definite energy states for ammonia molecule (Feynman Lecture Volume III Chapter 9.1)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, hamiltonian, molecules

I have a question regarding this text passage of the Feynman Lecture Volume III chapter 9.1:

[image]

Here $C_1$ and $C_2$ are the amplitudes for the ammonia molecule either beeing in state 1 or state 2. According to 9.4 $C_{II}$ is just the sum of both amplitudes, however, in the following text it is said, that $C_{II}$ describes the amplitude to be in a state where both original base states are equal. Why for example can't $C_1 = \sqrt{1/3}$ and $C_2 = \sqrt{2/3}$?

[Here](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_09.html) is the link to the full text, but the Question arises already in the first section.

EDIT: Ok, I think I understand it know, but I would like to rephrase it again to see if my understanding is correct.
So we start with $\langle II|$ = $\langle 1| + \langle 2|$. This means that $II$ is the state where the amplitudes of state 1 and state 2 are equal. Then we can write $$\langle II|\phi\rangle = \langle II|1\rangle\langle 1|\phi\rangle + \langle II|2\rangle \langle 2|\phi \rangle = \\ \langle 1|1\rangle\langle 1|\phi\rangle + \langle 2|2\rangle \langle 2|\phi \rangle = \langle 1|\phi\rangle + \langle 2|\phi\rangle = C_1 + C_2$$
If I am trying to understand it from this direction I have no troubles as I can simply follow the math. It seems like I was simply confused by just saying $C_1 + C_2 = \langle II|\phi\rangle$ without knowing how $II$ was defined. Also $C_1$ and $C_2$ are not telling anything about the state $II\rangle$ but about how likely it is to get from $\phi\rangle$ to $II\rangle$ and there of course $C_1$ and $C_2$ will be different for different $\phi\rangle$.

Comment: Note that he did not define $C_1 = C_2 = \sqrt{1/2}$. Rather, by defining $C_{II} = C_1 + C_2$ he is implicitly saying that $C_{II}$ contains equal parts $C_1$ and $C_2$, whatever they may be. A different definition is of course possible.

Comment: So with equal parts simply means that the amplitudes are just added as they are and not like using two times $C_1$ and only one time $C_2$? But for me the phrasing "II in which the amplitudes of the original base states are equal." sounds like $C_1$ has to be $C_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hes does not mean that $C_1$ and $C_2$ have to be equal, he is defining the bra $\langle \mathrm{II}|$ from the equation $\langle \mathrm{II}|\phi\rangle=\langle 1|\phi\rangle + \langle 2 |\phi \rangle$. Removing the ket - part on both sides of the equal sign gives the bra $\langle \mathrm{II}|=\langle 1| + \langle 2 |$. This bra, as you can see, have the same amplitude for the base states (bras).

Comment: But in the text he is explicitly mentioning that in state II the amplitudes of the original states are equal. And as far as I understand $C_1$ and $C_2$ stands for those amplitudes?

Comment: He defines $|\phi \rangle = C_1|1\rangle + C_2|2\rangle$. So $C_1$ and $C_2$ is the notation used spesifically for the amplitudes of the base states for $|\phi\rangle$. Then he defines the bra $\langle \mathrm{II}$. If we need to use a notation for the amplitudes of the base states of this bra, we have to use another notation than $C$, so as to not confuse it with $|\phi \rangle$, e.g. $\langle \mathrm{II}=D_1\langle 1| + D_2 \langle |2$. The (not normalized) expression for $\langle \mathrm{II}|$ in the question has $D_1 = D_2 = 1$.

Comment: I think I understood it know. Could you please check my edit, if my understanding is correct? Thanks!

Comment: Looks right. (Alternative way to the same result is $\langle \mathrm{II}|\phi\rangle = (\langle 1| + \langle 2|)|\phi\rangle = \langle 1|\phi\rangle  + \langle 2|\phi\rangle =C_1 + C_2$.)